# Factorizing ${ { A }_{ x } }^{ 2 }-{ { A }_{ x } }{ { B }_{ x } }-{ { A }_{ x } }{ { C }_{ x } }$ for an equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to make an equation so that $ { { A }_{ x } } $ is on the left hand side and move the rest to the right hand side,I did all I can,but I am stuck with those who left because they all have $ { { A }_{ x } } $ on them.

This is The equation:

$$
{ { A }_{ x } }^{ 2 }-{ { A }_{ x } }{ { B }_{ x } }-{ { A }_{ x } }{ { C }_{ x } }=(-\left\| AB \right\| .\left\| AC \right\| )-{ { B }_{ x } }{ { C }_{ x } }-{ { C }_{ y } }{ { B }_{ y } }+{ { A }_{ y } }{ { B }_{ y } }+{ { A }_{ y } }{ { C }_{ y } }-{ { A }_{ y } }^{ 2 }
$$

Comment: The left hand side is $A_x^2 - (B_x + C_x)A_x$. So, you have a quadratic equation.

Comment: I want the ${ { A }_{ x } }$ to be alone in the left hand side,As I am using it in a computer program.

Comment: You wrote that already. And I gave you a hint to do this.

Comment: Sorry,But I still can't solve it,Would you mind explaining?

Comment: Can't you solve equations like $x^2 + ax + b = 0$?

Comment: I can solve it,but how is that applied here?

Comment: I can't believe it, sorry. Look into my first comment. Don't you see any similarities between $A_x^2 - (B_x + C_x)A_x$ and $x^2 - ax$??

Comment: This will give me  $A_{ x }(A_{ x }-(B_{ x }-C_{ x })$ I still have the $A_x$,Sorry,I am in school,still learning.

Comment: Ok, treat $A_x$ as a variable as you would treat $x$ in $x^2 + bx + c = 0$.

Comment: The right hand side will be equal $A_x$ or $A_x-(B_x-C_x)$

Comment: Oh my... You should first learn to solve quadratic equations (although you already stated you can do that...). Ok, if you have $x^2 + bx + c = 0$, then this is the same as (using the binomial formula) $(x + \frac b 2)^2 + c - \frac{b^2}4 = 0$. Equivalently, $(x + \frac b 2)^2 = \frac{b^2}{4} - c$. Now, we take the square root on both sides, which gives $x + \frac b 2 = \pm\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{4} - c}$ (assuming that $\frac{b^2}{4} - c\ge 0$). Hence, $x = -\frac b 2\pm\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{4} - c}$. These are two solutions! Now, I hope you can do the same for your $A_x$.